# Does Ubuntu update its root certificate authority list automatically?

Tags: certificates, tls

Will the root CA list become outdated if I never restart/upgrade the OS? Or does Ubuntu periodically update the root CA list in the background automatically (without restart/upgrade)?

Comment: No, you have to [`sudo update-ca-certificates -v -f`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html). Chromium/Chrome also uses its own certificates store. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1129300/349837) is a related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root CA certificates live in the package [`ca-certificates`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ca-certificates&searchon=names&section=all). It is very rarely updated. Updating this package does not require a reboot. Note that Firefox uses its own certificate store.

Comment: But does it do it automatically?

Comment: @Lisa unless you setup unattended-upgrades, no packages are upgraded automatically