# Not connecting to unsecure websites

Tags: 16.04, websites

Chrome, Chromium, Firefox - all of the browsers are not allowing me to open websites which are marked unsecure in chrome. The only pages they open are those with green lock and `Secure`.

As this problem appears in all of the browsers I can assume that the problem is in system settings. I've just started using Ubuntu in dualboot from yesterday, before that I was using Ubuntu from VM and never faced this problem. Any help is appreciated.

---

Working sites:

- https://www.twitch.tv/
- https://askubuntu.com/
- https://www.youtube.com/
- https://www.heise.de/download/product/pycharm-92668

Not working:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/
- https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/
- https://jetbrains.ru/products/pycharm/

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. The problem is rather the webpages. Usually this happens if you open a `https` page which doesn't have a valid certificade. In any of the browser you mentioned there is an option (firefox e.g. on the bottom of the page -> advanced) to add an "unsave" page as exception.

Comment: What sort of internet connection are you using ? By "marked unsecure", you mean web addresses which begin with `http://` - ones which begin with `https://` all work ? I assume these websites work correctly in Windows ?

Comment: @JonasCz I am using DSL connection. No, chrome marks both `http://` and `https://` as unsecure. Yes, all of these websites work correctly in windows chrome or ios safari.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for comment, I've added the list to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate)

Comment: @ElderGeek if this is a duplicate, can you please explain what is the problem in my case?

Comment: See @derHugo comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992219/not-connecting-to-unsecure-websites?noredirect=1#comment1600428_992219) Here's another related post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/894475/does-ubuntu-update-its-root-certificate-authority-list-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easy solution

The solution in my case was just to switch from `16.04` to `17.10`, all the issues are gone.

### Less easy solution

If you are more experienced with ubuntu than I am, you can try to read comment section below the question post. The problem is related to site certificates. 
 Here are two questions which can help you to resolve this problem (thanks to Elder Geek):

- [How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate)
- [Does Ubuntu update its root certificate authority list automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894475/does-ubuntu-update-its-root-certificate-authority-list-automatically)