# List and remove unofficially installed CA certificates

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, certificates, privacy

[This article](https://malcolm.cloudflare.com/) expose how around 18% of HTTPS connections are being detected as intercepted by MITM proxies. As the great [related paper](https://jhalderm.com/pub/papers/interception-ndss17.pdf) states:

> To circumvent this validation, local software injects a self-signed CA certificate into the client browser’s root store at install time.
> [...]
> Contrary to widespread belief, public key pinning [19]— an HTTPS feature that allows websites to restrict connections to a specific key— does not prevent this interception. Chrome, Firefox, and Safari only enforce pinned keys when a certificate chain terminates in an authority shipped with the browser or operating system. **The extra validation is skipped when the chain terminates in a locally installed root (i.e., a CA certificate installed by an administrator)** [34].

It is pretty common [on companies](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/151868/147346), desktop antivirus and malware/adware to add a root CA. Sometimes even with honest reasons. But to [make the situation more clear](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6810/147346): *SSL web browsing is exactly as strong as the weakest CA* (this includes DNS, if [DNS-over-HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS)).

---

I want to check if my HTTPS traffic is intercepted at least in three aspects (better if just using CLI):

- **Google Chrome**/Chromium/Brave
- [**Firefox**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkvSH.png) ([Red Hat equivalent](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549043)?)
- **Ubuntu** official repos/Snap (See [ca-certificates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ca-certificates) & [ca-cacert](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ca-cacert). [Red Hat equivalent](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003)?)

So the real questions are:

- How to list unofficially installed CA certificates (doesn't come with Ubuntu/Firefox/Chrome) to avoid MITM attacks/HTTPS interception?
- How to reset trusted certificates stores to its default?

#### Some *research* and related questions

- [checkmyhttps](https://github.com/checkmyhttps/checkmyhttps) seems old and not trustworthy
- **Chrome**: `chrome://settings/certificates`.
  This is a subset of what return some of these commands?

  ```bash
  # System wide (I)
  awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '/BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

  # System wide (II) (`p11-kit` package)
  trust list
  ```
- [**Firefox**](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/Included_Certificates)

  ```
  certutil -L -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default*/
  ```
- I already [`sudo update-ca-certificates -v -f`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html). This just updates without removing any sneaky already installed certificate?

#### Reference

- [Chromium - Root Certificate Policy](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy)
- [Firefox: How to audit & reset the list of trusted servers/CAs](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549043)
- [How can I protect myself against software installing insecure root certificates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/106343/147346)
- [Who your browser trusts, and how to control it](https://certsimple.com/blog/control-the-ssl-cas-your-browser-trusts)
- [All root certificates that Firefox trusts for SSL/TLS](https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/mozilla/CACertificatesInFirefoxReport) ([from](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/Included_Certificates))

Comment: Firefox and Chrome come with their own certificate store which is independent from `/etc/ssl/...`. The latter is used by other tools like curl but some applications, libraries or tools come with their own CA store (Java, python requests ...). So it is not really simple to check all of these.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I didn't say it would be easy, and [as you know](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/151868/147346) is not rare. There are already some answers for Windows and [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003) out there.

Comment: [about:certificate](about:certificate) in Firefox will give you a live view of active certificates, but no management other than export.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -S somefile` will tell you what package somefile belongs to. You can use `dpkg --verify pkgname` or `debsums` to see if they have been modified.

You can use those to verify `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` and the directories it refers to -- basically, verify that CA files belong `ca-certificates` + `dpkg-reconfigure -plow ca-certificates` to chose among them. As you may have guessed, `update-ca-certificates` uses this data to recreate the global CA store files.

I don't have an easy answer for app-specific stores like Chrome's and Firefox's. You'd basically start by looking for global configuration directories, if any (`dpkg -L`), and then look into each user profile to see if custom CAs have been installed in that profile: look at the files, diff with a new one, check if the account is corporate-managed, ... StackOverflow or SuperUser can help more directly.

Obligatory note: installing packages from untrusted third parties can mess up the system in many ways (running any untrusted script, really). I think yours is still a fair question, since benign software sometimes adds a CA and won't try to hide the fact. However, if you suspect someone might have modified your system behind your back, it's *far* safer to reinstall.